# Firestoring Paging Adapter Crashes when switching fragments during loading state

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, paging, firebaseui

i have an application i am working on, i have initialized my firestore paging adapter using firestore ui paging library, everything works fine, but whenever i load my fragment, and firestore is still fetching data and i try switching to another fragment, my app crashes, giving me this error.

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
Process: com.simon.trepamobileadmin, PID: 12390
io.reactivex.rxjava3.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: [https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#error-handling) | java.lang.InterruptedException
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.single.SingleFromCallable.subscribeActual(SingleFromCallable.java:49)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single.subscribe(Single.java:4813)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:589)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:65)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:56)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1022)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:232)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzad.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:7)
at com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.FirestorePagingSource.lambda$loadSingle$0$FirestorePagingSource(FirestorePagingSource.java:42)
at com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.-$$Lambda$FirestorePagingSource$aRsAFsiduxRWbX-Rs8tsd39JsV0.call(Unknown Source:4)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.single.SingleFromCallable.subscribeActual(SingleFromCallable.java:43)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single.subscribe(Single.java:4813) 
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89) 
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:589) 
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:65) 
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:56) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12390 SIG: 9

This is how i initialize the paging adapter

```
       val options = FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<Feeds>()
    .setLifecycleOwner(viewLifecycleOwner)
        .setQuery(baseQuery, config, Feeds::class.java)
        .build()
    pagingAdapter = FeedsAdapter(options, requireActivity(), this, binding.root, lifecycle,
        resultLauncher!!,findNavController()
    )

    binding.feedsRecyclerview.adapter = pagingAdapter
    binding.feedsRecyclerview.layoutManager =
        LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
```

here is my adapter code

```
class FeedsAdapter(
    options: FirestorePagingOptions<Feeds>, var context: Activity, var interf: FeedsInterfaces,
    var root: View, var life: Lifecycle, var resultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>,
    var navController:NavController?=null
) :
    FirestorePagingAdapter<Feeds, FeedsAdapter.ItemViewHolder>(options) {

    class ItemViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var image = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.feed_image)
        val body = view.findViewById<ExpandableTextView>(R.id.feed_body)
        val title = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.feed_header)
        val options = view.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.feeds_item_options)
        val video = view.findViewById<YouTubePlayerView>(R.id.feed_video)
        val spinkit = view.findViewById<SpinKitView>(R.id.addfeed_progressBar)
        val textlayout = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.addfeed_textlayout)
        val date = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.feed_date)
        val like = view.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.love)
        val likes = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.feed_likes)
        val share =  view.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.feed_share)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        val view: View = if (viewType == 0) {
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.feeds_items_pic, parent, false)
        } else
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.feeds_items_vid, parent, false)
        return ItemViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int, model: Feeds) {
        model.ref = snapshot().items[position].reference
        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0)
            setForImage(holder, model)
        else
            setForVideo(holder, model)
        setClick(holder, position, model)

        holder.like.setOnClickListener {
            doLove(model, holder.like)
        }
        holder.date.text = model.date!!.convertDate()
        if(CONS.user!=null)
            registerLikes(model, holder.likes, holder.like)

    }

    fun refreshs() {
        refresh()
    }


    private fun registerLikes(model: Feeds, likes: TextView, button: MaterialButton) {
        FirebaseHelper().getFeedLikes(model).apply {
            checkIfUserLikes(this, button)
            addSnapshotListener { snapshots, e ->
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w("error", "listen:error", e)
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                } else {
                    if (snapshots != null) {
                        FirebaseHelper().getFeedLikes(model).get().addOnSuccessListener {
                            if (it.isEmpty) {
                                likes.text = "0 Likes"
                                checkIfUserLikes(this, button)

                            } else {
                                likes.text = it.documents.size.toString() + " Likes"
                                checkIfUserLikes(this, button)

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }

    }


    private fun checkIfUserLikes(ref: CollectionReference, button: MaterialButton) {
        ref.apply {

            document(CONS.user!!.userid.toString()).get().addOnSuccessListener {
                if (it.exists()) {
                    button.icon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_heart__red)
                } else {

                    button.icon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_heart)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun doLove(feed: Feeds, button: MaterialButton) {
        if (CONS.user != null) {
            val like = Likes()
            like.uid = CONS.user!!.userid
            FirebaseHelper().addFeedLike(feed, like, this, button)
        }
        else
            SnackBar.error(root,"You cant Like Feeds without signing in", SnackBar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    private fun setForImage(holder: ItemViewHolder, feeds: Feeds) {

        Glide.with(context).asBitmap().thumbnail(0.1f).load(
            feeds.thumblink
        ).into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                holder.image.setImageBitmap(resource)
                holder.spinkit.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

            }

        })
        holder.share.setOnClickListener {
            val sk = SnackBar.success(root,"Initializing Image to Share", SnackBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).apply{show()}
            Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(
                feeds.link
            ).into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: Bitmap,
                    transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                ) {
                    CONS.share(resource,context,root,resultLauncher)
                    sk.dismiss()
                }

                override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

                }
            })

        }
        //  GlideHelper().loadImage(feeds.thumblink.toString(),feeds.link.toString(),holder.image,context,holder.spinkit)
        holder.body.text = feeds.body
        holder.title.text = feeds.title
        holder.image.setOnClickListener {
            holder.image.transitionName = feeds.link.toString()
            ImageViewHelper().showImage(
                feeds.link.toString(),
                feeds.thumblink.toString(),
                context,
                feeds.body,
                holder.image,
                navController!!
            )
        }
    }

    private fun setForVideo(holder: ItemViewHolder, feeds: Feeds) {
        YoutubePlayerHelper().Initialize(feeds.title.toString(), holder.video, context)
        holder.title.text = feeds.body
        life.addObserver(holder.video)
        holder.share.setOnClickListener {
            val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
                action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+feeds.title)
                type = "text/plain"
            }
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+"${feeds.title}"))
        }

        // holder.title.text = feeds.title
    }

    private fun setClick(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int, feeds: Feeds) {
        holder.options.setOnClickListener {
            if (holder.itemViewType == 0)
                ContextMenuHelper().showBottomSheet(
                    context,
                    interf,
                    0,
                    feeds,
                    this,
                    image = holder.image,null,position
                )
            else
                ContextMenuHelper().showBottomSheet(
                    context,
                    interf,
                    1,
                    feeds,
                    this,
                    video = holder.video!!,position = position
                )
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val feed = snapshot().items[position].toObject(Feeds::class.java)
        return feed!!.type
    }



}
```

please help me, my app crashes whenever i changed fragment when adapter is loading or i wait till loading finishes before changing

Comment: Since you are using Kotlin, I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android-c485acb0a2df) will help. If you are interested in Jetpack Compose as well, then this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-76b4c0b5acd5) will also help.

Comment: i dont wanna have to implement paging from scratch, that is why i used the one provided by firebase ui, but i dont know if its a bug or something, i even tried surrounding it with try and catch block, but it doesn't work

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: did you read my question? i said it works, but when my application launches and firestore is still fetching data and i try to switch to another fragment either from my bottom navigation view or using findnavcontroller.navigate the application crashes, giving the error i listed above,

Comment: I am getting a similar error. using firebase-UI v8.0.2 with fragments